# How to add value to objects current value

Tags: javascript, object

This might be a simple question, but im having problems trying to add a value to an objects current value, I need to use a key to access the object.

The majority, not all values and object values are string format. I am trying to parse to int caluclate the two elements and replace the object.

- Is there a more elegant method of achieving this?
- How can I prevent int from parseing int, incase that arises?

Attempt:

```
if(object[key] == undefined)
{
   object[key] = 0;
}
object[key] = parseInt(object[key]) + parseInt(value);
```

Comment: `object[key] = object[key] !== undefined ? object[key] + parseInt(value) : 0;`

Comment: @Tushar Is `object[key] = object[key] !== undefined` strictly equivalent to `typeof  object[key] !==  "undefined"`?

Comment: @Tushar : My test of obj-value + value (5+5) ...equals 5, im expecting 10. This doesnt seem to add the two together?

Comment: @Orbitall Can you replicate issue? http://jsfiddle.net/g6oLogbv/  If `object[key]` is undefined, it would return 5 as expected behaviour. I could miss something

Comment: Sorry, i completly miss the point of the question(s): `Is there a more elegant method of achieving this?
How can I prevent int from parseing int, incase that arises?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of truthiness/falsiness, you can try this (as a starting point):

```
// To satisfy Mr Wolf complaining about 'object' and/or 'key' being undefined:
var object = {};
var key = "potato";

// Then, continuing with my actual answer:
object[key] = parseInt(object[key]) || 0;
value = parseInt(value) || 0;

object[key] += value;
```

If `object[key]` is `undefined` or invalid (IE: `parseInt(object[key])` returns `NaN`), it receives the value `0`.  Likewise with `value`.

Comment: @Mr.Wolf if object isn't undefined regarding OP's question. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: o0o0o wolf-on-wolf combat!  Clearly, @Mr.Wolf, OP has not posted the entirety of his code.  I think it's safe to say he has `object` and `key` variables in scope prior to this code block.

Comment: @A.Wolff His code works **only** *`object` and `key` have been defined successful*. As you can see, he doesn't define it before. So, the correct must be: `object` and `key` are undefined. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wolf so... what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Mr.Wolf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854534/how-to-add-value-to-objects-current-value/33854709?noredirect=1#comment-55473808

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer defining the variables.  No more `object is undefined` problem.  Happy? :D

Comment: ya. I'm happy now. haha =))

Comment: @Alex McMillan: Yeah this is exactly the more elegant method of achieving it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by ducktyping the obj[key] (in case its undefined, it will be assigned 0) and simply adding a "+" in front of value to make sure it adds it as an number instead of a string

See the console for the output

```js
var obj = {}, key = 'missing';
var value = "5";

obj[key] = +(obj[key] || 0) + (+value);
console.log(obj[key]);

obj[key] = +(obj[key] || 0) + (+value);
console.log(obj[key]);
```

In case you really want to abstract the adding and handling, I guess it would make more sense to go for a small function (or an extended function that uses the arguments list as in the second example)

```js
'use strict';

var obj = {}, key = 'val', value = "5";

function sum(a, b) {
  return (+(a || 0)) + (+(b || 0));
}

function sumAll() {
  var total = 0, i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
    total = sum(total, arguments[i]);
  }
  return total;
}

obj[key] = sum(obj[key], value);
console.log(obj[key]);
obj[key] = sumAll(obj[key], value);
console.log(obj[key]);
```

Comment: Why `+` instead of `parseInt` or `parseFloat`?

Comment: @Rudie that's a shorthand to convert to number but less readable and not equivalent to `parseInt()` regarding float number passed or string value

Comment: @Rudie like A. Wolff said and simply because it is one of the tricks you can use in Javascript, so language dependent, you could say for javascript that should be readable. Assigning a default value with ducktyping and casting to int with a shorthand function

Comment: I know **what** it is. I was wondering **why** you used it. Speed, readability, support?, etc, all good reasons.

Comment: @Rudie readability + flexibility (no reason to use parseInt before you actually need to have an int at hand)